# Her leg was impaled on steel rod

Tags: grammar, headlinese

> Her leg was impaled ***on*** steel rod.
>
> The boy was impaled **by** steel rod.
>    [Boy, 10, impaled by steel rod - The Star Online](http://www.thestar.com.my/News/Nation/2014/11/06/Boy-10-impaled-by-steel-rod/)

I am a bit confuse by the preposition used in the sentences above.
These sentences are get from the online newspaper.

What is the sentences above mean?

Comment: These don't appear to be sentences from an online newspaper.  They're basically ungrammatical.  (They can be saved with a marginal interpretation of *steel rod* as non-count substance, but this is probably not what you intended.)

Comment: Please add the source so that we can see the full context.

Comment: @jimsug Check this.
http://www.thestar.com.my/News/Nation/2014/11/06/Boy-10-impaled-by-steel-rod/
and
http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/world-news/schoolgirl-impaled-11-inch-steel-rod-4261677

Comment: Thank you. The fact that it is the headline means that each of the people who answered below could have saved a lot of time. Their answers do not apply to headline clauses, as they have special rules around sentence structure. Please include sources in all of your future questions, to avoid people wasting their time unnecessarily.

Comment: Please don't edit quotes without telling us you're doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Her leg was impaled **on** *a* steel rod.

At some point in the past, she had a steel rod in her leg.

> Her leg was impaled **by** *a* steel rod.

At some point in the past, a steel rod stabbed through her leg.

The difference in meanings is subtle, but in the second, the steel rod is given some agency, as if it chose to stab her through the leg.  This focuses our attention on the action of being impaled rather than on the state of being impaled.

This doesn't work with people or animals or even inanimate objects that are moving (that I can think of.)  In those cases we would always use "by."

> I was stabbed **by** a madman.
>   I was bitten **by** a dog.
>   I was hit **by** a car.

Another case where we might use on or by, with the senses that I gave above.

> Her dress was snagged on a thorn as she ran past.
>   Her dress was snagged by a thorn as she ran past.

We imagine the thorn reaching out to snag her dress in the second example.

Answer (score 0):

They should be

> Her leg was impaled on a steel rod.
>
> The boy was impaled by a steel rod.

The difference is which object is stationary and which is moving. (Really!)

In the first sentence, the steel rod is stationary and her leg was moving. In the second sentence, the boy was stationary and the steel rod was moving.

I don't know what preposition to use when describing an impalement when both impaled object and impaling object are moving.

(p.s. Where did these events occur, by the way, and why do they have so many steel rods?)